# Update line item properties in cart with file upload

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I need to be able to update the line item properties in the cart. The issue I'm having is that two of the properties include a file upload.

As of now the properties that aren't the file upload do update but I'm getting this error
{"status":"bad_request","message":"Parameter Missing or Invalid","description":"Required parameter missing or invalid: 'line' or 'id' param is required"}

Here is my code:

```js
function updateCart(id) {
    let formElement = document.querySelector('form[action^="/cart/change.js"]');
    formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.set('id', formData.get('product_key'));

    return fetch('/cart/change.js', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        body: formData,
        success: function(){
            window.location.reload()
        }
        
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('update cart successfully with:', formData);
            
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
};
```

```html
<div class="edit-prop-container">
                                  <form action="/cart/change.js" method="post" class="update-cart-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                                  <input type="hidden" value="{{ line_item.key }}" name="product_key">
                                  {% assign loop_index = forloop.index %}
                                  {% for property in line_item.properties %}
                                    <div class="property-field">
                                    {% assign first_character_in_key = property.first | truncate: 1, '' %}
                                    {% unless first_character_in_key == '_' %}
                                        <label id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}" class="property-label">{{ property.first }}: </label>
                                        {% assign showProp = property.first %}
                                        {% case showProp %}
                                        {% when 'First Logo' %} 
                                          <div id="firstLogoPreviewCart" class="logo-preview">
                                            <img id="firstPreviewCart" src="{{ property.last }}" loading="lazy" width="200" height="200"/>
                                            <p id="firstErrorMessageCart"></p>
                                            <input type="hidden" data-name="{{ property.first }}" name="properties[First Logo]" class="propLine update-textarea autosize new-property" id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}-firstLogo firstLogo{{ line_item.product_id }}" value="{{ property.last }}">
                                          </div>
                                          <input type="file" id="firstLogoUploadCart" data-current-value="{{ property.last }}"  onchange="firstLogoCartUpload({{ line_item.product_id }})">

                                        {% when 'First Location' %}
                                          <button type="button" class="button" id="showFirstLocationCart" onclick="ShowFirstLocationCart()">Show Locations</button>
                                          <div id="firstLocationCartContainer">
                                            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0580/9602/5772/files/FrontCenter_256x256_crop_center.png?v=1661857523" height="150" width="150" loading="lazy"/>
                                            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0580/9602/5772/files/RightPanel_256x256_crop_center.png?v=1661857523" height="150" width="150" loading="lazy"/>
                                            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0580/9602/5772/files/LeftPanel_256x256_crop_center.png?v=1661857524" height="150" width="150" loading="lazy"/>
                                          </div>
                                          <select name="properties[First Location]" id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}-firstLocation" class="propLine update-textarea autosize new-property"  data-current-value="{{ property.last }}" data-name="{{ property.first }}">
                                            
                                            {% if property.last == "Front Center"%}
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Front Center" >Front Center</option>
                                              <option value="Right Panel" >Right Panel</option>
                                              <option value="Left Panel" >Left Panel</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Right Panel" %}
                                              <option value="Front Center" >Front Center</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Right Panel" >Right Panel</option>
                                              <option value="Left Panel">Left Panel</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Left Panel" %}
                                              <option value="Front Center" >Front Center</option>
                                              <option value="Right Panel" >Right Panel</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Left Panel" >Left Panel</option>
                                            {% else %}
                                              <option value="Front Center" >Front Center</option>
                                              <option value="Right Panel" >Right Panel</option>
                                              <option value="Left Panel" >Left Panel</option>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            
                                          </select>
                                        {% when 'Second Location' %}
                                          <button type="button" class="button" id="showSecondLocationCart" onclick="ShowSecondLocationCart()">Show Locations</button>
                                          <div id="secondLocationCartContainer">
                                            <img id="secondLocationImgCart" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0580/9602/5772/t/10/assets/secondLogo_Locations.png" height="248" width="400" loading="lazy">
                                          </div>
                                          <select name="properties[Second Location]" id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}-secondLocation" class="propLine update-textarea autosize new-property"  data-current-value="{{ property.last }}" data-name="{{ property.first }}">
                                            {% if property.last == "Back Center" %}
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Back Center" >Back Center</option>
                                              <option value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option value="Back Right" >Back Right</option>
                                              <option value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option value="Right Side">Right Side</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Back Left" %}
                                              <option value="Back Center">Back Center</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option value="Back Right" >Back Right</option>
                                              <option value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option value="Right Side" >Right Side</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Back Right" %}
                                              <option value="Back Center" >Back Center</option>
                                              <option value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Back Right">Back Right</option>
                                              <option value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option value="Right Side" >Right Side</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Left Side" %}
                                              <option value="Back Center" >Back Center</option>
                                              <option value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option value="Back Right">Back Right</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option value="Right Side">Right Side</option>
                                            {% elsif property.last == "Right Side" %}
                                              <option value="Back Center" >Back Center</option>
                                              <option value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option value="Back Right" >Back Right</option>
                                              <option value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option selected="selected" value="Right Side">Right Side</option>
                                            {% else %}
                                              <option value="Back Center" >Back Center</option>
                                              <option value="Back Left" >Back Left</option>
                                              <option value="Back Right" >Back Right</option>
                                              <option value="Left Side" >Left Side</option>
                                              <option value="Right Side" >Right Side</option>
                                            {% endif %}
                                          </select>
                                        {% when 'Second Logo' %}
                                          <div id="secondLogoPreviewCart" class="logo-preview">
                                            <img id="secondPreviewCart" src="{{ property.last }}" loading="lazy" width="200" height="200"/>
                                            <p id="firstErrorMessageCart"></p>
                                          </div>
                                          <input type="file" class="propLine update-textarea autosize new-property" id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}-secondLogo"  data-current-value="{{ property.last }}" data-name="{{ property.first }}" value="{{ property.last }}" name="properties[Second Logo]">
                                        {% when 'Second Logo Simple Text' %}
                                          <input type="text" class="propLine update-textarea autosize new-property" id="{{ line_item.product_id }}-{{ property.first | handleize }}-secondLogoSimpleText"  data-current-value="{{ property.last }}" data-name="{{ property.first }}" value="{{ property.last }}" name="properties[Second Logo Simple Text]">
                              
                                        {% endcase %}
                                      
                                      {% endunless %}
                                    </div>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  
                                    <button type="submit" class="property-popup cart-line-item-update button button--primary" title="Save changes" data-index="{{ loop_index }}" onclick="updateCart({{ line_item.id }})">Update</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="property-popup cart-line-item-cancel button button--secondary" title="Cancel" onclick="cancelPropPop({{ line_item.id }})">Cancel</button>
                                </form>
                                  </div>
```

If you have a better solution for updating the line item properties with a file upload I'm all ears.

Comment: the usual pattern is to accept the upload at the product level when it is first added to cart. Did you verify first that that was working for you? If not, perhaps try mastering that pattern first, as Shopify provides working code for that, as opposed to the cart.

Comment: Yes, the file is originally uploaded from the product page. I need to be able to change the uploaded file from the cart.

Comment: My point is, your needs are one things, working code another. If you uploaded a file at the product level, before you hit the cart, and it is correct in the cart for that product, that is one thing. If you have not succeeded at that, ensure you do that. Only once you've mastered that would you try an upload from the cart. It is very rare you see line item properties for uploads at the cart. Hence my original comment to you. You are already in rare turf.

Comment: @DavidLazar The upload does work at the product page. Hence why I'm working on changing the upload in the cart now. I have a similar call to /cart/change.js as I do for /cart/add.js, however the call to /cart/change.js is not working like the call to /cart/add.js. I realize this is rare turf, but I still need a solution for it.

Comment: My two cents is, Shopify does not support updating file uploads. Your mileage may vary of course. Hope it works out for you.